# LVM Device-mapper (dm-2) 100% busy

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-usage, load, device-mapper

We have set up LVM stripping across 06 disk in our DB server for improving IOPS performance.

However during heavy load, it has been observed that device-mapper **dm-2** asscociated with these 6 disks is having 100% utlization (busy), but the associated disks **sd[c-h]** have only ~50% utilization.

Bcoz of the heavy load and 100% utilization, DB server, hence app performance also degrades.

Here is the screenshot of busy percentage:
[image]

Here is LV details:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg/lg
  LV Name                lv
  VG Name                vg
  LV UUID                P**-***-***e
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2022-12-02 20:32:38 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                13.08 TiB
  Current LE             13715376
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2
   
  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 13715375:
    Type        striped
    Stripes     6
    Stripe size 16.00 KiB
```

Below is the block size of the underlying file system:

```
$ sudo stat -f /lvm-fs
  File: "/home/.../lvm-fs"
    ID: ***    Namelen: 255     Type: xfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 3510614400 Free: 2161893661 Available: 2161893661
Inodes: Total: 1404454400 Free: 1404453939
```

Is there any configuration/settings such that **dm-0** and other disks should experience equal utilization %  so that IOPS performance can improve further ?

Thanks.

**Edit-1:**
Output of linear read using **dd** :

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/dm-2 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=102400 
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
107374182400 bytes (107 GB) copied, 184.611 s, 582 MB/s
```

For above **dd** command, busy % kept fluctuating between `65%` and `85%`, but never touched `100%` whereas **dm-2** was always `100%` busy as below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: 16 KiB stripe size seems a bit weird to me, but then I don't have benchmarks, [maybe related](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=linuxonibm/performance/tuneforsybase/lvm.html)?

Comment: I wonder whether there really is a problem or whether we are just shown one... How is this utlization measured? Are those spinning disk drives or SSDs/NVMes? What happens (to the utlization display) if you just read linearly? `dd if=/dev/dm-2 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=102400`

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks for the link... shall try with the different stripe size as mentioned there.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Our concern is that purpose of stripping is to have equal write load across all disks. Earlier, in non-stripe lvm setup, only single disk and dm-2 was 100% busy at a time. Now post-stripe setup, though busy'ness is equal across 06 disks, it is still unequal w.r.t dm-2, due to which we feel that disks are not utilized to their full capacity as dm-2 is getting 100% busy before the disks.
The utilization output screenshot is taken from **nmon**. These are 15K SAS HDD (12G). Question is edited to add the output of linear read using `dd`.